# Neuroscience Graphics with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

Does anyone know of packages for displaying neuroscience schematics with tikz? For example, I would like to place a raster plot next to the diagram of a Markov process to help explain how Markov models could be used to simulate the firing of neurons.

I know that I could do this by including an image of neural activity in the tikz picture. But, I wondered if there was a solution that could only use tikz.

Below is the, admittedly, amateurish, version I made in PPT. The raster plot refers to the horizontal lines of ticks. Each tick is the same and marks where a neuron fired.

I know how to use the automata library in tikz to make the state diagram. I wondered if there was an easier way to draw many horizontal lines than the brute force approach with a for loop.

[image: Sketch of slide combining raster plots and Markov chain]

Sample neural data (times in ms that a neuron fired) for 50 ms:

```
 2,10,12,14,15,20,25,34,35,48, 49
```

Comment: Can you please provide (a link to) an image of the kind of drawing you would like to do?

Comment: Could you provide some sample "neuron firing" data? Otherwise random numbers it is. The color represents intensity? (There are lines of different color: black, orange, red)

Comment: Random numbers are fine. Most simulations use a Poisson process with a rate of 10. I've edited to provide some example times though. There should only be one color-black. The rasters are pasted from another program into PPT and the coloring is an artifact when two black lines are really close together.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the neuron activity part:

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%\pgfmathsetseed{42}% or some other number
\foreach \y [count=\c] in {-0.5,-1,...,-2.5}
    {   \node[right] at (15.2,\y+0.1) {\scriptsize Subject \c};
        \foreach \x in {1,...,300}
        {   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\drawbool}{rand-0.7 > 0 ? 1 : 0}
            \ifthenelse{\drawbool=1}
                {   \fill (\x/20,\y) rectangle (\x/20+0.05,\y+0.3);}
                {}
        }
    }

    \draw[-stealth] (0,0) -- (15.5,0);
    \node[right] at (15.5,0.2) {t in ms};
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \v using int(20*\x)] in {0,...,15}
    {   \draw (\x,-0.05) -- (\x,0.05) node[above] {\v};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: That's beautiful.

Comment: How would I position the state diagram and the raster plot in the same tikz picture?

Comment: Just take the state diagram commands and put them in a shifted scope: `\begin{scope}[shift={(x,y)}] <draw commands> \end{scope}`

Comment: @Ahmed Musa: It's random numbers, so they are different after each compile. To make them stay constant, add `\pgfmatsetseed{<number>}` before the first `foreach`. I added it in the answer.